# No Class Definition error while using OpenCV

Tags: java, android, opencv

I am trying to use this [tutorial](https://github.com/vanevery/JavaCV_0.3_stream_test) for streaming a video to a server. I can successfully import and compile the code in Android Studio and can run. When I try to run, it shows

> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException:
>   `com.googlecode.javacv.cpp.opencv_core`

when I try to debug. I found out that it gives error in:

```
yuvIplimage = IplImage.create(imageWidth, imageHeight, IPL_DEPTH_8U, 2);
```

where `yuvIplimage` is instance of `IplImage`.

Comment: javacv != opencv java bindings. javacv builds upon deprecated c-api structures. avoid it.

Comment: I also prefer opencv java bindings, but javacv is a good alternative if you need features not currently in the Java bindings.  Your problem looks like Android Studio doesn't know where to find the javacv classes.  You probably need to setup some kind of module dependency on the JavaCv jars, or define them as libs somehow in the gradle files.  I'm still getting use to the new Android Studio gradle stuff for defining libs, so I'm not exactly sure how the recommended way to do that is.

Comment: Hi all, I am able to solve the issue by including the javacv-android-arm.jar in the libs however it worked on some phones and crashed and show the same issue in different phone